# How to programmatically copy content(Paragraphs,Tables,etc.) in order from a Word document using Office.Interop.Word?

Tags: c#, import, ms-word

I need to import a Word document by parts and store in a DB. The following code works well with paragraphs, but other items like Tables, images are missing.

```
foreach (Word.Paragraph item in this.oDoc.Paragraphs)
{
    r = item.Range;
    r.Copy();
    SaveInDB();
}
```

I need to keep the document order of paragraphs,tables,etc. as they appear so I cannot process each separately unless there were some way to check the order of each item.

Comment: The Word object model is not designed for what you wish to do. I recommend you consider "parsing" the Word Open XML of the documents, instead, possibly using the Open XML SDK. The way the Word Open XML file format is stored you can "walk" it from front to back, picking up the content in order. How to best store it in a database is another question, entirely, and would depend on what the purpose is for storing it in this manner in a DB to begin with.

Comment: How does MS do it?
After the copy I do a paste into a WPF RichText Control which keeps the formatting without having to do any transformations (such as I would need to do if I used the xml content). So I do not want to use the xml way.
The rest of my app, the SaveInDB function is done. Previous we were copy/pasting content manually. It works well, but now we want to import whole documents.

Comment: So, if you want to add the whole document, is there a reason you can't copy/paste it all in one go? If not, can your DB store Word tables with all their formatting? As for images, what you're asking may not be possible for no other reason than the use of text wrapping. How would you propose to handle an image with text wrapped around it (possibly on both sides) or placed behind the text?

Comment: @macropod Thank you for the idea. I tested copying the document.content to the WPF RichControl and it maintains the formatting that is required. I can then separate the paragraphs and tables in order to store in our DB as content nodes. The hard part will be extracting the image data and knowing from which paragraph/table it came from.
This is a new requirement for a 10 year old IETM (Interactive Electronic Technical Manual) program.  The formatting that is required for IETM from Word works. Text around images is not needed.

Comment: In the case of floating images, you can test the anchor location, but that has no particular relationship to where the image physically appears. getting the physical position or a wrapped shape is also not that hard (see the VPos & HPos refs in the VBA code @ http://www.msofficeforums.com/word/37352-making-image-caption-together.html#post121711), but you'll then need to test the physical positions of the paragraphs (and any other shapes on the same page) to determine the correct order - in some case, there will be none.